# Extract Header and Table text from a .docx file

Tags: python, python-2.7, win32com, python-docx

I'm trying to extract page and header data from a docx file. The file is several hundred pages, each with a table and a header. The header has pertinent information that needs to be paired with each table. I'm able to extract the header and table data, I just can't reliably pair them together.

Using win32com this is what I've got so far

```
# getting the table page number
app = Dispatch("Word.Application")
doc = app.Documents.Open(filename)
table_1_page = doc.Tables(1).Range.Information(3) # 3 == wdActiveEndPageNumber
```

The problem occurs because the headers TextFrames and are duplicated on multiple pages, so when I call:

```
# getting the header page number
doc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(1).TextFrame.TextRange.Information(3)
```

I get one of the pages that the TextFrame occurs on. The page is chooses seems somewhat arbitrary, sometimes its the first others its the last, but its not predictable.

I'm spent a bit of time reading over the object model [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff837519.aspx). Ultimately it would be nice to capture all of the items displayed per page without reinventing the wheel.

### EDIT 10/25/16 per request, here is some minimum working code**

```
# filename docx_parser.py

import pythoncom


class OpenDoc(object):
    def __init__(self, docx_path):
        import win32com.client as win32
        self.path = docx_path
        self.word = win32.Dispatch("Word.Application")
        self.word.Visible = 0
        self.word.Documents.Open(p)
        self.doc = self.word.ActiveDocument

    def get_table_count(self):
        return self.doc.Tables.Count

    def count_table_rows(self, table):
        return table.Rows.Count

    def count_table_columns(self, table):
        return table.Columns.Count

    def get_headers(self):
        headers = self.doc.Sections(1).Headers(1)
        shape_count = headers.Shapes.Count
        for shape_num in range(1, shape_count + 1):
            t_range = headers.Shapes(shape_num).TextFrame.TextRange
            text = t_range.Text
            page_num = t_range.Information(3)  # 3 == wdActiveEndPageNumber
            yield text, page_num

    def get_table_text(self, table):
        col_count = self.count_table_columns(table)
        row_count = self.count_table_rows(table)

        for row in range(1, row_count + 1):
            row_data = []
            for col in range(1, col_count + 1):
                try:
                    row_data.append(table.Cell(Row=row, Column=col).Range.Text.strip(chr(7) + chr(13)))
                except pythoncom.com_error as error:
                    row_data.append("")

            yield row_data

    def get_all_table_text(self):
        for table in self.get_tables():
            table_data = []
            for row_data in self.get_table_text(table):
                table_data.append(row_data)
            yield table_data

    def get_tables(self):
        for table in self.doc.Tables:
            yield table

    def __del__(self):
        self.word.Quit()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        path = r"sample.docx"
        open_doc = OpenDoc(path)
        for table_num, table_text in enumerate(open_doc.get_all_table_text()):
            print("\n-------------- Table %s ----------------" % (table_num + 1))
            for row_data in table_text:
                print(", ".join(row_data))

        for header_text, page_num in open_doc.get_headers():
            print("header page number: %s, text: %s" % (page_num, header_text))
    except Exception as error:
        from traceback import format_exc

        print(format_exc())

raw_input("")
```

Comment: Please clarify "all of the items displayed per page without reinventing the wheel". Also does each table fit on one page?

Comment: The tables don't necessary have to fit on one page. Basically the headers refer to a person and the tables refer to information about that person. I can give a link to a sample document if that would be helpful

Comment: An example with page numbers that you expect would help.

Comment: Here is a small redacted sample https://www.dropbox.com/s/fpl5f9qcup7oshv/sample.docx?dl=0  The actual document is 723 pages and the table formatting can vary (exported from a PDF)

Comment: Thx for the exame input.  But as stated please provide an exame of output you want when you run your script on that sample.

Comment: the name, SS# etc is added to a 'Person' object and the data from columns 3-9 is added to an 'Event' object stored in each Person object.

Comment: Ok now we're getting somewhere. You'll have to post an MCVE of code that reproduces the problem, including what that script outputs when you run it on the sample you posted. Then I can run it on my system and fiddle around with it.

Comment: Just to clarify, does your 723 page document contain different information (name, ss#..) in the page headers? So one could expect between 2 and 723 different headers?

Comment: It's about 140 different headers, about one new one every 2-5 pages

Comment: hey, user2682863! I'd love to have a look at a part of your document, to see how the file is structured. Perhaps we can find another way to extract those headers. I created a chat room if you want to discuss: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126961/extract-headers-from-docx